# Java : Object Initialization

Tags: java

How to interpret the statements below:

```
Notes bean = null;
bean = new Notes();
```

Small explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: It would help if you'd give context, and also explain which bits you already understand and which bits you're confused by.

Comment: @Jon: I am trying to understand different ways of object creation, let's say for second statement if am not initializing it to Null than can I make both statements equivalent, if yes then how ?

Comment: If you just did `Notes bean;`. 'bean' will automatically be set to null. I don't understand how they two statements can be construed as equivalent at all. Can you explain?

Comment: You're wrong about the initialization order you might want to rewrite that as @robob sugested

Comment: @shoebox639: Local variables aren't initialized automatically. You have to definitely assign a value before it's read.

Comment: @Jon Mea culpa, I was thinking instance variables. Those get initialized to default values while you must always initialize local variables.

Comment: Why downvote ? Can't I clear my confusion on stackoverflow ?

Comment: We are trying, however, you haven't given us enough to work with. And you still haven't said how the two statements can be equivalent. Or why you are trying to turn it into equivalent.

Comment: I am not trying to turn it into equivalent. I want to understand what is the difference and wanted to go through the explanation of how above statements would work and so I got my doubt cleared

Comment: In which case I think all the answers below tell you exactly what they do. `Notes bean = null;` will declare a variable `bean` of type `Notes` to have a value of `null`. While your second line takes the variable `bean` and assigns a newly created `Notes` to. After these two lines, `bean` will be a newly created instance of `Notes'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure the sequence of the instruction is not the opposite?

```
Notes bean = null;
bean = new Notes()
```

It seems a mistake :-)

Maybe could be:

```
Notes bean = new Notes();
bean = null;
```

In this case it can be used to signal to the garbage Collector that it has to trash the object referenced by Bean.

Otherwise I guess it a mistake. Could you post more code?

Answer (score 1):

one step back:

```
    Notes bean;
```

this is a field or a local variable declaration without explicit initialization.

A field will be initialized with a default initial value: `null` for objects, `0` for primitive numbers and char, and `false` for boolean. 
A local variable will stay uninitialized. It's an error to access such variable until a value is assigned to it.

---

```
    bean = new Notes();
```

is assigning a value to the field or variable. In this case a new instance of `Notes` is created and assigned<sup>*</sup>  to `bean`. Similar to:

```
    bean = null;          // kind of assigning 'nothing' or 'empty'
    bean = someMethod();  // assigning the value returned by the method
```

<sup>* actually it is the reference to the instance that is assigned to `bean`</sup>

---

```
    Notes bean = null;
```

is the combination of both: declaring a field or variable, and assigning a value to it (initializing it). In this case the value is `null`, which means the same as no instance.
These is almost equivalent to writing

```
    Notes bean;
    bean = null;
```

The variable could also be initialized with an new instance of `Notes`:

```
    Notes bean = new Notes();
```

Answer (score 0):

new creates a new instance of the object, which allows you to use it as expected (such as accessing its methods)

null essentially means it references nothing (and thus you can't use any of its methods)

Comment: So how can I make 2nd statement equivalent to first statement ?

Comment: Notes bean = new Notes(); Or just switch the order of the statements. I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at. new Notes() can never be equivalent to null

Comment: yes but if am not pointing it to null then can i make both statements equivalent, am trying to understand object creation, may be example given here is not good.

Comment: Notes bean = new Notes(); does not have an equivalent. Notes bean; is equivalent to Notes bean = null;

Answer (score 0):

```
bean = new Notes();
```

This statement assumes you've already delcared a variable named bean of type Notes (or any of its parent classes. If you just run this line by itself, it will blow up because it can't find the variable 'bean'.

```
Notes bean = null;
```

This here will initialize a variable 'bean' and have it point to nothing. A variable is just a pointer to a spot in memory where your object will reside.

You should switch the order of these 2 statements, or combine then like:

```
Notes bean = new Notes();
```

Comment: "This statement assumes you've already initialized [...]" -> should be "declared" instead of "initialized".

Comment: @Bruno: Can you elaborate your explanation ?

Comment: @shoebox639: Am creating bean as new instance of Notes class than how will it assume that variable named bean is already initialized, can you provide some more explanation ?

Comment: @Rachel. Because you have to declare the variable `bean` first. Without the declaration, java will through a compile error as it can't find the variable `bean`. I'm also taking your two statements as separate ones. If they are not separate, then they are in the wrong order.

Comment: @Rachel, declaring a variable is giving it a name before doing anything with it (telling the compiler it's going to be used), for example `Notes bean;`. Then you have the assignment that sets its value, for example `bean = new Notes();`. You can combine both in one line `Notes bean = new Notes();`. Initializing a variable is the first assignment of the variable (within the same statement as the declaration or after).

Answer (score 0):

First statement creates an initialize fields on the bean object (a Notes object),

`Notes bean = null`, is the declaration of a bean reference that doesn't reference to an actual object (that's the meaning of null), referencing to null means that you can't use bean and its methods.

If the statementes are within the same block of code (enclosed by the same pair of `{}`), the program won't compile, because you're declaring the same reference twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
bean = new Notes();
```

This assumes that you have a variable named "bean" that has already been declared.  The type of bean must be Notes or one of its parent classes or an interface implemented by Notes.  The "new" keyword along with the parameter-less constructor call signify the creation of a new object of type Notes and the variable bean references that new instance.

```
Notes bean = null;
```

This declares a variable named "bean" of type Notes.  It also initializes the variable to null.  Variables that are fields are initialized to null by default (unless they are primitives), but local variables are not initialized to anything by default.  Thus this line explicitly initializes bean to null.